# Cart totals block is not loading

Tags: magento2.2.2

Totals block in shopping cart page is stuck.
[image: error]

The Error in console is:

```
POST http://www.demomage.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/totals-information 500 (Internal Server Error)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check network tab - to see the response 
Response should be a json
it is probably an html - with some errors[image]

P.S I could not make a comment

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution - bug fix.

https://github.com/ekuusela/magento2/commit/aa535ea5d4bf78915bddd4387a9d3c4b39943eea

In that fix you propably have the most of the code. In my case i was missing.

In line 15 add  `use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface;`

In line 98 add `unset($addressTotalsData[ExtensibleDataInterface::EXTENSION_ATTRIBUTES_KEY]);`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119392)

Comment: yea sorry i edit it